# Subsets that add up to zero in finite sequence {1,-1,1-1..}

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

This problem must be simple, but it's driving me crazy

(Following the comments I edit)
If I have for example the following sequence  $\{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1\}$  and ask how many subsets of two elements add up to zero, it's easy, since the are four 1s and four -1s, the result is $4\cdot4=16$ pairs add up to zero.

But my question is How about all the subsets of 4 elements that add up to zero?...and 6 elements?...and in general for an arbitrary and finite sequence such that there is always the same number of 1s as -1s, how to calculate all the subsets that add up to zero?
As said in comments in a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_{2n}$ where $a_i=(-1)^i.$ How many $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ such that $|I|=k$ and $\sum_{i\in I}a_i=0$

Comment: That's not a set.  If you pick an element $1$, say, how are we to know which one you meant?

Comment: There is no meaning to repetitions in a set. What you wrote is just the set $\{1, -1\}$, doesn't matter how many times you write the elements.

Comment: Aside from the technical issues mentioned by lulu, you can think of the problem as follows: Say you have $N$ distinct red and $N$ distinct blue balls. Given some integer $k \leq N$, in how many ways can you pick $k$ red balls and $k$ blue balls?

Comment: Then, "set" should be replaced with "multiset".

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of subsets or $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size $i?$

Comment: Even in multi sets, the number of sub-multisets  is not defined this way. There is only $1$ subset of size $1$ of the multiset $\{1,1\}.$ You really need a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_{2n}$ where $a_i=(-1)^i.$ Then ask how many $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ such that $|I|=k$ and $$\sum_{i\in I}a_i=0$$ @GeoffreyTrang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence has even length since it has the same number $n$ of $1$s as $0$s.

You know there are $n^2$ ways to find two element sets that sum to $0$.

There are $z = \binom{n}{2} = n(n-1)/2$ ways to choose two $1$s and the same number of ways to choose two $0$s so $z^2$ subsets of size $4$.

Can you finish?